# Asp.net core Tables for Identity not being created in the database

Tags: database, asp.net-identity

When I see at other sample projects, the number of tables created for supporting Identity in the db is great (such ones as AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, etc..), but in my case when I make the migration and the update only the User table has been created. What is the reason?
Here is my code in the startup, in the dbcontext and my class user:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>( options =>
                             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:photoarchiver:ConnString"]));
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole > (
                opts => {
                    opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    opts.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
                    opts.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                    opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        }
```

Class DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Photos).WithOne(i => i.User);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>().ToTable("Photos");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>().HasOne(i => i.User).WithMany(u => u.Photos);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Categories");

        }

        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Class User:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: See if changing your `ApplicationDbContext` to extend from `IdentityDbContext<User>` instead of just `DbContext` makes a difference. You will have to re-make your migrations. `IdentityDbContext` comes from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace

Comment: Wehn I do so and I add the migration I get an error:The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.

Comment: I have added base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); in the OnModelCreating method nd now the migration seems to be successful and it seems to contain all the tables for identity. I will go on and see if the database gets correctly created.Thanks for your help

Comment: you can post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get all the `AspNetRoles, etc` tables "for free" you need to change your `ApplicationDbContext` to extend from `IdentityDbContext<User>` instead of just `DbContext`. `IdentityDbContext<T>` is found in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace. You can see from the source code https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/EF/IdentityDbContext.cs, `IdentityDbContext` will bring in the required `DbSet`properties. 
As you correctly identified in the comment to your question, you will need to call `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` and re-make your migration files.